# Data save coding problems

Tags: python, scrapy

this is spider

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import scrapy
from scrapy_test.items import ScrapyTestItem
class QiushiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "qiushibaike"
    start_urls = {
         "http://www.qiushibaike.com",
    }
    def parse(self, response):
        item = ScrapyTestItem()
        for temp in response.xpath(".//div[@id='content']//div[@id='content-left']/div"):
            # a = str(map(str, ''.join(temp.xpath(".//div[@class='content']/span/text()").extract())))
            item['text'] = temp.xpath(".//div[@class='content']/span/text()").extract()
            item['number'] = temp.xpath(".//div[@class='stats']/span[@class='stats-vote']/i/text()").extract()
            yield item
```

This is the pipeline that holds the data

```
import json
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
class ScrapyTestPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()
        self.file = open("aaa.jl", "w",encoding='utf8' )
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item['id'] = hash(''.join(item['text']))
        if item['id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s " % item)
        else:
            line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
            self.file.write(line)
            return item
```

I tried to save the data, but the data encoding went wrong.I tried to do it in other ways, but I failed. What should I do?

*this is error data*
"text": ["\n\n\nlz\u7537\uff0c\u4eca\u5929\u8ddf\u670b\u53cb\u53bbktv\u5531\u6b4c\uff01]

Answer (score 0):

How did you run your scraper? you are saving data into JSON/CSV by using scrapy's default exporters?

Do this in `settings.py`

```
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import scrapy
from scrapy_test.items import ScrapyTestItem
import re
class QiushiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "qiushibaike"
    start_urls = {
         "http://www.qiushibaike.com",
    }
    def parse(self, response):
        item = ScrapyTestItem()
        for temp in response.xpath(".//div[@id='content']//div[@id='content-left']/div"):
            a = temp.xpath(".//div[@class='content']/span")
            id = temp.xpath('.//@id').extract_first('')
            item['id'] = re.search('[0-9]*$', id).group(0)
            item['text'] = (''.join(a.xpath("string(.)").extract())).strip().encode('utf-8')
            item['number'] = temp.xpath(".//div[@class='stats']/span[@class='stats-vote']/i/text()").extract_first('')
            yield item
```

this is pipeline

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
class ScrapyTestPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()
        self.file = "liu.jl"
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s " % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['id'])
            with open(self.file, 'a',encoding='utf-8') as f:
                f.write('text: '+item['text'].decode() + '\n')
                f.write('number '+item['number'] + '\n')
                f.write('id '+item['id'] + '\n\n')
            return item
```